# sap.m.Switch - Change event not getting triggered

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i'm just starting with UI5 and i'm currently stuck with an issue using sap.m.Switch with UI5 Version 1.71.33.
Basically what i want to achieve is, when the state of the switch changes, another field on the form should be switched on/off accordingly.

The switch is defined as follow

```
            Switch type="AcceptReject" id="idSwitch" state="false" enabled="true" change="_onSwitchChange">
                <layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                </layoutData>
             </Switch>
```

And in my controller i defined the _onSwitchChange function as follows:

```
    _onSwitchChange: function() {
        
         if ( this.getView().byId("idSwitch").getState() ) {
           this.getView().byId("idF2").setEditable(true);
       } else {
           this.getView().byId("idF2").setEditable(false);
       }
    }
```

Any idea why the event is not getting triggered or any suggestion how else i can achieve the expected result?
Thanks already for any help!

Best regards

Comment: If you place a breakpoint or console.log() inside the function, does something happen?

Comment: nothing happens when i set a breakpoint inside _onSwitchChange and than use the switch, it is just like this function never gets called and i don't understand why. And i also noticed i seem to have a general issue with change-event, for exameple i have a smartfield and tried to use events valueListChanged and change, here i have the same issue it just seems like those events never get triggered for some reason.

Comment: Is your controller properly connected to the view? (redefine onBeforeRendering and set a breakpoint there).

Comment: This acutally hinted me to the solution, thank you so much!!! I was using a main view and an additional fragment in which i defined the form, but my controller was only for the main view. I fixed by just moving the form to the main view, didn't really need the fragment anyway. Out of curiousity, would there be a way to link main view controller to the fragment so that it is linked to both?

Comment: If the fragment is part of the view then they should automatically share the same controller. Would need to see some code on how the fragment is embedded into the view.

Answer (score 0):

In general this can and should be solved using a local (view) model.

In the `onInit` function create a new `JSONMOdel`

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "./BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    ... // and so on
], function (Controller, JSONModel, ... /* and so on */) {

    return Controller.extend("my.namespace.controller.Main", {
        
        onInit() {
            const oViewModel = new JSONModel({
                elementEditable: false
            });
            this.setModel(oViewModel, "view"); // if you don't have a baseController use this.getView().setModel(...)
        }

        // and so on
    });
});
```

And in your view

```js
<Switch state="{view>/elementEditable}" />

...
<YourElement editable="{view>/elementEditable}" />
```

When your switch is pressed the variable in your model will be changed. Elements that are also bound to this variable will then be updated immediately.